# Issue with conda create environments:(Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams)

Tags: python, conda

i use conda created a new python 3.6 environment, then i use instructions like pip or python it comes out the same error:

```
(mypy36) C:\Users\admin>python
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\abc.py", line 64, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_abc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\abc.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\_py_abc.py", line 35
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, /, **kwargs):
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(mypy36) C:\Users\admin>conda list -n mypy36 python
# packages in environment at D:\anaconda\envs\mypy36:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
python                    3.6.2                         0    https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free

(mypy36) C:\Users\admin>python -V
Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

i have tried set PATHONPATH="", it doesn't work.

can anyone help?

Comment: i use the command `conda create -n mypy36 python =3.6` created the environment

Comment: Thanks for adding that info. Does launching with `python -s` work?

Comment: Thank you for answering, i reinstall the anaconda and repeat the process, there is no any errors